# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on 24" Aluminum iMac (heat and boot issues)

Tags: 14.04, boot, mac, lts, overheating

Specs:
Memory: 3.9 GiB
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T7700 @ 2.40 GHz x 2
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV630
OS-type: x64bit
Disk 2.0 TB

I salvaged a 24" Aluminum iMac and installed 14.04 LTS on it. It has worked surprisingly well for 2 years (other than the hard drive heating up to 55 degC after extended use, and YouTube). However, I recently changed the password and have forgotten it. Trying to reset it using the reboot, left shift after BIOS method has proven unsuccessful. I decided to try to reinstall 14.04 from the DVD. The system will not try to boot from the disc. Does anyone have any pointers on how to get around all this without reformatting or replacing the hard drive or any other drastic methods?

There may be other shortcut keys that I need to use when rebooting. Upon reboot the mac startup sound comes on, along with a blank white screen, before it proceeds to a black screen for some seconds, and the, a black screen with a purple border. Then it goes blank again before displaying the following:

`[   9.333029] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents`

`[   9.566675] INFO @w1_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy`

Then Ubuntu starts. I have tried a number of times, but I just can't hack it without spending a lot of precious time.

All help is greatly appreciated. Also, any recommendations for the heating up issues. The fans seem to be running, but may not be working as well? I installed a high-performance HDD from Western Digital, but I have considered an Eco, or high efficiency one with less heat output, or a solid state.

Comment: Open the laptop and remove the lint from the fan exhaust is always a good step. Compressed air all around finishes the job.

Comment: In my own personal experience, I found that both Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 ran quite hot on my laptop, which was a fairly new i7 with SSD's and 8GB of RAM.  My fan was always quite loud.  Even at idle I was getting 60+ ceclius.  I could only deduce that it was Unity creating all the heat.  I switched to Ubuntu Gnome and found my system ran much cooler, and was also more responsive.  Average temps with Ubuntu Gnome are between 43 and 53 when idle and 60 when working now.